# Navigate through previews pages asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, sitemap

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

But the problem is that I don't have only 2 levels of previews paths, I can have many.

You can see below all the possible ways for paths:
Home > advanced search > [project's name]

Home > projects listing > [project's name]

Home > advanced search > [media's name]

Home > media listing > [media's name]

Home > advanced search > [media's name] > [project's name]

Home > media listing > [media's name] > [project's name]

Home > advanced search > [actr's name]

Home > actors listing > [actor's name]

Home > advanced search > [actr's name] > [actor's name] > ...[actor's name] > [project's name]

Home > actors listing > [actor's name] > [actor's name] > ...[actor's name] > [project's name]

**Generally:**

Being on an actor, you can navigate through actors and through projects.
Being on a prject, you can't navigate anywhere else.
Being on a media, you can navigate only through projects.

I know  that there is the `javascript:history(-1)`, but I also want to know the name of the previews media, actor, or if it is actor,media or project listing, or advanced search.

The only thing I thought of is: when someone chooses a project(onclick of a link) when being on **projects listing** to just have a global variable, change the `numOfRoute` and also store the name **"project listing"** on a `String` table. 
The same with all the others: when being on an actor, store his name and increase variable.

So when being on `project.aspx` page have a loop passing through that table of names using `history(-1, -2, -3 ..)` to those links.

Moreover another problem is that `onclick` of the link on CodeBehind I have to change those Global variables via javascript.

I don't know how really things work out, I am not sure if there is a better way, I am a begginer on web design programming. How do they cope with this?

Comment: Why don't you use the [`SiteMapPath`-control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.aspx)?

Comment: Just to add on to Tims comment.... SiteMapPath is awesome because is so easy to use... Just set up your menu as a tree and then drag the SiteMapPath control on your page and it does everything for you

Comment: Really? I didn't know this thing, I will try it!

Comment: Site Map: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp

Comment: thank you very much guys! Can I use my own image for this ">" symbol too?

Answer (score 0):

The following code example shows site-map data

```
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode title="Home" description="Home" url="~/default.aspx" >
    <siteMapNode title="Demo" description="demo" 
      url="~/Demo.aspx">
    <siteMapNode title="XYZ" description="xyz" 
      url="~/XYZ.aspx" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

You can add a SiteMapPath control to the XYZ.aspx by:

```
 <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" Runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
```

When XYZ is viewed in the browser, the SiteMapPath control displays something like

> Home > Demo > XYZ (as hyperlinks)

Comment: So, I have to make a `<siteMap>` now with all my medias, actors and projects stored in my database?
Moreover if he wants to go bavk to advanced search I must also store the string he searched, so if the search string is "as" the link must be: url="~/search.aspx&q=as">

Comment: Yes you have to make <siteMap> for the entries you want to browse. Well i cant say for advance search thing, because it might throw an error called 'invalid tag' or something like that. If it's not giving an error then go ahead, its worth giving a shot. Also, as an alternate method, if you want to change URL at advance search or something like that, you can create an onClick method to the <siteMap> tag.Something like this: <siteMapNode title="Parent" url="Page1.asp#T1" onClick="Func('Page1.asp#T1')"> and define function apprpriately

Comment: this is impossible, it is a CMS website, and the users add more and more projects, actors, medias. I tried to insert those parameters programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425(v=vs.100).aspx, but always this error occurs: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context